# Como parar o $(window).scroll num consulta sob demanda

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rolamento

Faço uma consulta sob demanda na minha página, eu trago as informações do banco enquanto o usuário usa o scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    var init = $(".canal .lista ul#dem").length;
    carregar(init + 1, init + 2, 'lista_load.asp');
});
```

O problema é q não sei como parar o scroll, eu faço uma verificação, fiz uma validação para que quando chegasse no fim dos itens me mostrasse um alert, e funcionou bem, queria nesse ponto que a função do scroll parasse de trazer s itens, mas não sei como fazer, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: já tentou o evento.stopImmediatePropagation() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O evento `scroll` não dá para cancelar. Isso é muito claro [na especificação da W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-type-scroll).

As únicas maneiras que sei para contornar isso são:

- `overflow: hidden;`
- um oscultador de evento que força a posição do scroll a não mudar

**A primeira opção**, de dar `overflow: hidden;` no body é muito usada em casos onde o `scroll` não deve acontecer. No teu caso queres que o `scroll` funcione até dada altura e depois pare de funcionar. Para usar esta ideia tens de ler a posição do scroll e aplicar o `overflow: hidden;` no `body` ou elemento pai do outro.

Exemplo:

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 4000px;
    border: 1px solid #ccf;
}
.pararScroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > 1000) document.body.classList.add('pararScroll');
});
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51p1tq4u/**

**A segunda opção** precisa que guardes o valor da ultima posição do scroll. Assim a cada evento `scroll`, voltas a dizer que a posição deve ser a anterior a esse evento `scroll`.

Exemplo:

```
var lastScroll;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    if (lastScroll) return window.scrollTo(0, lastScroll);

    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > 1000) lastScroll = scrollTop;
});
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51p1tq4u/1/**

E se quiseres voltar a ativar o scroll só tens de mudar o valor de `lastScroll` para um valor que tenha valor booleano `false`.